# JavaScript heap out of memory' error while running node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core, npm

I am using Angular 5 .NET core template to build our application but our project has become too huge, whenever I publish my project I am getting an error: "JavaScript heap out of memory."

I have tried many solutions.

I have used `npm i increase-memory-limit` to increase memory limit.

I have also tried this node `--max_old_space_size=8000`.

But I am not getting the correct solution.

Help me for .netcoreangular5 template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> please try this  try this i am sure you will get solution.

1. right click on your project choose edit project file.
2. find Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish".
3. replace

   Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod"

   Exec Command="node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod"

   with

   Exec Command="node --max_old_space_size=10240 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod"

   Exec Command="node --max_old_space_size=10240 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod"
4. publish it again, it will work for javascript-heap-out-of-memory-error.

Comment: i was stuck with this error for 2 days, now you have saved me thanks a lot this solution work for me.